# Garbage collection not working on Google Colab

Tags: python, garbage-collection, google-colaboratory, large-files

I am trying to load data into google colab from a dataset of large files. I only need a part of the data from each file. So, I am doing manual garbage collection after storing only the required part. However, it does not seem working. It is getting disconnected after loading only a few files after showing high RAM usage. Here is the code snippet.

```py
import numpy as np
import tqdm

selected_id = 5
slices = np.zeros([len(file_list), n, m]) # len(file_list)=1428, n=225, m=75 
for k, file_path in enumerate(tqdm(file_list)):  
    snapshot = np.load(file_path) # snapshot.shape = 201, 225, 75
    snapshot -= mean 
    slices[k] = snapshot[selected_id]
    del snapshot
    gc.collect()
```

The code is getting stuck at k=10. I am using the High RAM option (~25 GB). The code runs perfectly on my local machine which has lower RAM than google colab.

Comment: You're keeping all the snapshots in the `slices` array. There's nothing to collect.

Comment: @Barmar snapshot is a 3D array. I am just keeping the last 2 dimensions from each snapshot by selecting a specific index from the first dimension

Comment: Sorry, misread it.

Comment: Could it be possible that `snapshot[selected_id]` is returning a [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html) of `snapshot` and causing a reference to be retained in memory? Try `slices[k] = snapshot[selected_id].copy()`. Does it make a difference?

Comment: `file_list` is not defined, where does this come from ?

Comment: @D.L It's obviously just a list of paths? Even if you had its contents, this example would be irreproducible since you don't have the actual files it's pointing to

Comment: so `file_list = ['path_to_file_1.txt', 'path_to_file_2.txt' ... 'path_to_file_n.txt' ]`....

Comment: @D.L yes, file_list is just a list of paths file_list = ['path_to_file_1.npy', 'path_to_file_2.npy' ... 'path_to_file_1428.npy' ]. n=1428

Comment: I feel there problem specific to google colab. The code works on my local machine.

Comment: @thariqfahry the solution you proposed didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe something like `slices[k,:] = snapshot[selected_id,:]` to get a copy into the existing table.